# Cosmosdb: allowed access from all network but still getting Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I had my comsosdb instance with a private endpoint and Now I deleted it and switched to an open to all network configuration.

This is my simple python client:

```
import pymongo

uri = "XXXmyuriXXX"
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
mydb = myclient["db"]
mycol = mydb["faculty"]

mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37" }

x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

The XXXmyuriXXX is the one provided in Python quickstart.

As described by the title I updated the firewall to allow access from ***all network*** to access to the cosmos db (testing phase) but still I am getting anhautorized error.

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Error=13, Details='Request originated
from IP 62.216.203.210 through public internet. This is blocked by
your Cosmos DB account firewall settings. More info:
https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-forbidden ActivityId:
6645e180-f1bc-424c-9628-c7391264e282, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.14.0
Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.19041.0, full error: {'ok': 0.0,
'errmsg': "Error=13, Details='Request originated from IP
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX through public internet. 
This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings. More info:
https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-forbidden\r\nActivityId:
6645e180-f1bc-424c-9628-c7391264e282, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.14.0
Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.19041.0", 
'code': 13, 'codeName':{'Unauthorized'}
```

The error says something about the firewall rules but there should not be any since I selected the allo-from-all-networks option. Any guess on how to access the cosmodb?

Answer (score 1):

By default Azure Cosmos DB is accessible without any restrictions over the internet.
see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-vnet-service-endpoint
[image]

Have you tried running the Quickstart for connecting a python app to MongoDB API ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/create-mongodb-python

Also you uri needs to be the **connection string**. what value did you use for the uri here `uri = "XXXmyuriXXX"`? did you use the connection string or just the endpoint?

You can find the connection string here :
[image]

And make the connection like below :

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING)
try:
    client.server_info() # validate connection string
except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
    raise TimeoutError("Invalid API for MongoDB connection string or timed out when attempting to connect")
```

Comment: Yeah I copied the code from the quick start guide from the portal. I think the problem was that I had a private endpoint and I deleted it so somehow there was a configuration that was blocking the connection inside, I solved by creating a new cosmosdb from scratch